# Svelte custom event on svelte typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, svelte, svelte-3

I'm using clickOutside directive on my svelte-typescript project and I'm getting this error when I assign custom event to the related element

```
Type '{ class: string; onclick_outside: () => boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'onclick_outside' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>'
```

here's a snippet of my code

```html
{#if profileToolbar}
<div
    transition:fly={{ y: -20, duration: 300 }}
    use:clickOutside={profileToolbarContainer}
    on:click_outside={() => (profileToolbar = !profileToolbar)}
    class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md
    shadow-lg z-10 shadow-md">
```

this is the clickOutside directive that I'm using currently https://svelte.dev/repl/0ace7a508bd843b798ae599940a91783?version=3.16.7

I'm new to typescript so I don't really know where to start with my google search, anyone knows how to tackle this issue? thanks for your help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, so existing answers did work only partly for me. Given that the `clickOutside` action fires a custom event named `click_outside` i arrive at following solution:

```
declare namespace svelte.JSX {
    interface HTMLProps<T> {
        onclick_outside?: (e: CustomEvent) => void;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the only one actually working, should be marked as answer

Answer (score 35):

According to the [doc](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#im-using-an-attributeevent-on-a-dom-element-and-it-throws-a-type-error), you can create a `.d.ts` file in your project somewhere. And put inside that file the following:

```
declare namespace svelte.JSX {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    onclick_outside: () => void
  }
}
```

Please read the doc for more detail.

Comment: Works perfectly!, i just need to change it to `interface HTMLProps`, thanks for the help and the advice man, i'm aware that svelte typescript is still new, but unfortunately i'm not the one making the decision atm, but i'll make sure to remember your words

Comment: To hackape: I know this is a little off topic, but could you share some of the other inconveniences you experienced while using Svelte with TS? I'm one of the maintainers in that area and feedback like this is really valuable (because it's rare).

Comment: @dummdidumm I know bridging the two is not easy, so kudos to the work! But sorry I don’t have much to share cus it was more than half a year ago and I don’t remember much about specific things. I can only remember the general impression about the experience was acceptable, but not totally satisfying. At the end of day I thought to myself better just keep the TS things in `.ts` file as much as possible and import into `.svelte` file to lessen the melange and ignore warnings. Later on I switch back to the comfort world of react 

Comment: I was trying to port the svelte repl into vscode extension, but got interrupted then dropped it halfway. I can find time to dust off and refresh my memory. If I have anything worth sharing I’ll get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Things should be better now half a year later, but I agree that there are still some rough edges. About your REPL: In case you only want the "show compiled output" behavior of the REPL, that is now possible through the Svelte for VS Code extension. Command is "Svelte: Show Compiled Code".

Comment: Ah okay. I want the preview feature too. Are you maintainer of the vscode extension?

Answer (score 16):

This declaration worked for me

```
declare namespace svelte.JSX {
  interface DOMAttributes<T> {
    onclick_outside?: CompositionEventHandler<T>;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to specify the location of your custom type declarations in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Where do you put this?

Comment: @Marcus and future readers: SvelteKit comes with a `app.d.ts` inside the `src` folder. That's a fine location, also if you're using "plain" Svelte. In comparison, Angular used to generate a `typings.d.ts` in its `src` folder for the same purpose.

Answer (score 13):

**Update 7/23/23**

New SvelteKit requires this:

Here is my `src/app.d.ts` file.

```
// See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#app
// for information about these interfaces
declare global {
    namespace App {
        // interface Error {}
        // interface Locals {}
        // interface PageData {}
        // interface Platform {}
    }

    declare namespace svelteHTML {
        interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
            'on:clickOutside'?: CompositionEventHandler<T>;
        }
    }
}

export { };
```

J

Comment: For those looking at this answer: A gotcha in this new format is that the property includes the colon `:` in the property name. So `on:clickOutside` instead of `onclickOutside`

Comment: My custom event and class is called `clickOutside`, so it works for me.

Answer (score 6):

For me the following worked:

```
declare namespace svelteHTML {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
        "on:click_outside"?: CompositionEventHandler<T>;
    }
}
```

inside your `src/app.d.ts`.

based on [this](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#im-using-an-attributeevent-on-a-dom-element-and-it-throws-a-type-error)

Answer (score 1):

You can now simply do

```js
const dispatch = createEventDispatcher<{
    mounted: { id: string; store: FSStore }
    destroyed: { id: string }
  }>()

onMount(() => {
  dispatch('mounted', {
      id,
      store: fsStore,
  })
  return () => {
      dispatch('destroyed', {
        id,
      })
    }
})
```

This will then be fully typed:

```html
<Explorer
  on:mounted={onExplorerMount}
  on:destroyed={onExplorerDestroy}
/>
```

[image: ide preview]