# Svelte (svelte-kit) type custom action event with typescript

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

i'm using clickOutside action bellow.

```
export function clickOutside(node: HTMLElement) {
 function detect({ target }: MouseEvent) {
   if (!node.contains(target as Node)) {
     node.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('clickoutside'));
    }
  }
   document.addEventListener('click', detect, { passive: true, capture: true });
   return {
     destroy() {
       document.removeEventListener('click', detect);
    },
  };
```

This is the error that i still get, when i hover over on:clickoutside={() => {}}

```
Type '{ onclickoutside: () => void; class: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'onclickoutside' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>'}
```

I tried this in svelte kit `app.d.ts`

```
declare namespace svelte.JSX {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    clickoutside?: (event: CustomEvent) => void;
  }
}
```

i tried also `HTMLProps<T>` and `HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>` and many other variations and nothing works. I restarted ts server 25 times so it's not that.
this is the link for [docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#im-using-an-attributeevent-on-a-dom-element-and-it-throws-a-type-error)

And no, this is not a duplicate because i literally went through all the other answers and they don't work. like this one: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64131176/svelte-custom-event-on-svelte-typescript)

Answer (score 5):

I actually just had the same issue, and the [docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#im-using-an-attributeevent-on-a-dom-element-and-it-throws-a-type-error) do offer a great solution.
what I did was to modify my `app.d.ts` to include my interface.
here is my action:

```js
import { browser } from '$app/environment'

let iob: IntersectionObserver

const initializeIob = () => {
  console.log('called')

  iob = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const customEventName = entry.isIntersecting
        ? 'viewportEnter'
        : 'viewportExit'
      entry.target.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(customEventName))
    })
  })
}

const viewport = (element: HTMLElement) => {
  if (!iob && browser) initializeIob()

  iob.observe(element)

  return {
    destroy() {
      iob.unobserve(element)
    },
  }
}

export default viewport
```

you can see that I have `viewportEnter` that needs to be used with `on:` in my **html element**
The modified àpp.d.ts` looks like this:

```js
declare global {
  namespace App {
    // interface Error {}
    // interface Locals {}
    // interface PageData {}
    // interface Platform {}
  }
  namespace svelteHTML {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
      'on:viewportEnter'?: (event: CustomEvent) => void
      'on:viewportExit'?: (event: CustomEvent) => void
    }
  }
}

export {}
```

using it in my **html element**

```html
<h1
  style="text-align: center;"
  use:viewport
  on:viewportEnter={() => {
    console.log("Entered");
  }}
  on:viewportExit={() => {
    console.log("Exit");
  }}
>
  Hello Actions with Intersection observer!
</h1>
```

and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The correct current declaration should be:

```
declare namespace svelteHTML {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
        'on:clickoutside'?: (event: CustomEvent) => void;
    }
}
```

(Older versions used a different namespace/types, see [migration guide](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#im-getting-deprecation-warnings-for-sveltejsx--i-want-to-migrate-to-the-new-typings).)

Comment: doesn't work, i tried that already. very strange

Comment: Do you get the error when running `svelte-check`? Are your packages and the Svelte extension up to date? You can also try to restart the Svelte language server, there is a command for that if you use the VS Code extension.

Comment: yes all up to date, i also tried interface DOMAttributes<T extends EventTarget> {
    clickoutside?: (event: CustomEvent) => void;
  } that doesn't work. i restarted svelte and ts server and deleted all node_modules and .svelte-kit and every cache and still have an error. who cares ill leave it as it is, its not big of a deal for now, i will fix it later most likely by an accident. Thanks for help