# How to add types to custom events in svelte actions and use directive

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I am currently looking for a way to add types to the custom events emitted from the custom action to be used in `use directive` I am creating. Here is the snippet.

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const acceptedNodeNames = [
  //
  "INPUT",
  "SELECT",
  "TEXTAREA",
];

// prettier-ignore
type FormField =
  | HTMLInputElement
  | HTMLSelectElement
  | HTMLTextAreaElement;

type SubmitConfig = {
  schema: {
    [key: string]: z.Schema;
  };
};

export function form(node: HTMLFormElement, { schema }: SubmitConfig) {
  // store fields that needs to be validated in array
  const fields = Array.from(node.children).filter(
    (child) => acceptedNodeNames.includes(child.nodeName) && (child as FormField).name in schema,
  ) as FormField[];

  function handleInput(this: FormField) {
    const { name, value } = this;

    const result = schema[name].safeParse(value);

    if (result.success) {
      this.removeAttribute("aria-invalid");
    } else {
      this.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "");
    }
  }

  // attach field listeners
  for (const field of fields) {
    field.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e: SubmitEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const input = fields.reduce(
      (obj, field) => ({
        ...obj,
        [field.name]: field.value,
      }),
      {},
    );

    const result = z.object(schema).safeParse(input);

    if (result.success) {
      const event = new CustomEvent("okay", { detail: { ...result } });
      node.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
      const errors = JSON.parse(result.error.message);

      for (const error of errors) {
        const field = fields.find(({ name }) => name === error.path[0]);

        if (!field) continue;

        field.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "");
      }

      const event = new CustomEvent("fail", { detail: { errors } });
      node.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
  }

  // attach form submit handler
  node.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

  return {
    destroy() {
      node.removeEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

      for (const field of fields) {
        field.removeEventListener("input", handleInput);
      }
    },
  };
}
```

It basically just validates form field and uses `zod` underneath. This is how I would like to use it.

```html
<form
  novalidate
  method="POST"
  use:form={{
    schema: {
      email: z.string().email(),
    },
  }}
  on:okay={(e) => {
    console.log(e.detail);
  }}
  on:fail={(e) => {
    console.log(e.detail);
  }}
>
...
</form>
```

This code is already working, but my only problem is that it doesn't have types and it got some annoying squiggly lines in `vscode`. Is there a way at the moment to declare a type to those custom events similar to adding types in svelte components like so

```js
 interface $$Events {
    change: CustomEvent<{
      page: number;
      pageSize: number;
    }>;
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Svelte (svelte-kit) type custom action event with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73025100/svelte-svelte-kit-type-custom-action-event-with-typescript)

Comment: Thanks @H.B. will check this out later today

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the return type of your action function as `ActionReturn` which then allows you to type any custom attributes/events applied on the element.

Something like this:

```js
import type { ActionReturn } from 'svelte/action';

type SubmitConfig = {
  schema: {
    [key: string]: z.Schema;
  };
};

interface Attributes {
    'on:okay': (e: CustomEvent) => void;
    'on:fail': (e: CustomEvent) => void;
}

export function form(node: HTMLFormElement, { schema }: SubmitConfig): ActionReturn<SubmitConfig, Attributes> {
  ...
}
```

See here: https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#im-using-an-attributeevent-on-a-dom-element-and-it-throws-a-type-error