# Astro fails with svelte-testing-library

Tags: typescript, svelte, astrojs, svelte-testing-library

I'm building a website using [Astro](https://astro.build/) and a [Svelte](https://docs.astro.build/de/guides/integrations-guide/svelte/) integration. For testing I added [svelte-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/svelte-testing-library/intro) which runs fine when being executed with `npm test`.

Unfortunately after adding the component tests running [astro check](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/cli-reference/#astro-check) fails for all calls to `render()` with

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(component: Constructor<SvelteComponent<any, any, any>>, componentOptions?: any, renderOptions?: Omit<RenderOptions<typeof import("/workspaces/workspace/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries")>, "queries"> | undefined): RenderResult<...>', gave the following error.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(component: Constructor<SvelteComponent<any, any, any>>, componentOptions?: any, renderOptions?: RenderOptions<Queries> | undefined): RenderResult<...>', gave the following error.

11   render(Greeter, { name: "Luke Skywalker" });
               ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've created a Code Sandbox to repdroduce the issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/dfzwxh?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fgreeter.svelte&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2gvsfc00063b6htcg9fu6x%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60.02822201%252C39.97177799%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2gvsfc00023b6h1xtitq0h%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2gvsfc00043b6heq0ihd8w%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2gvsfc00053b6hce1wjry3%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B53.09342194698286%252C46.90657805301714%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu2gvsfc00023b6h1xtitq0h%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2gvsfc00023b6h1xtitq0h%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu8i75hn00023b6hykocjas6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252Fgreeter.svelte%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu8i75hn00023b6hykocjas6%2522%257D%252C%2522clu2gvsfc00053b6hce1wjry3%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2gvsfc00053b6hce1wjry3%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A4321%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2prsnl00bk3b6gpoxcfeo7%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu2prsnl00bk3b6gpoxcfeo7%2522%257D%252C%2522clu2gvsfc00043b6heq0ihd8w%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2gvsfc00043b6heq0ihd8w%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu2pmmkt01393b6gi40vap5n%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2pgg0a00qh3b6g4o25yf7h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2gvsfc00033b6h6vyrct26%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cluaxa0dp000jd9jpaix93ul6%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2pmmkt01393b6gi40vap5n%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cluax9w5i000hd9jp5x3wcpd4%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D). In `components/greeter.svelte` you can find the Svelte component, and in `components/greeter.test.ts` you can find the corresponding test.

As `npm test` runs through fine, I'd expect `astro check` to also run through without any errors.  Any ideas on how to fix the error?

Comment: `astro check` runs the typescript compiler while `npm test` doesn't. (similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76652489/svelte-native-typescript-errors-no-overload-matches-this-call)